# Retrieving data from Matlab plot with limited axis

Tags: matlab, plot, findall

How can I retrieve data from Matlab plot window with limited axis? Code:

```
plot(ua,va,'rO');
axis([-320 320 -240 240]); box on;
lh=findall(gcf,'type','line');
xp=get(lh,'xdata');
yp=get(lh,'ydata');
```

If there is no data on the plot window, xp and yp will give me data from the plot function (no window itself).

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "limited axis" and "no window itself"?

Comment: Are you trying to only get data within the figure that's being shown?

Comment: @b3 limited axis-axis that I limited with [-320 320 -240 240]; I want data from the plot window. For example, you set limits for the axis, and when you call plot Matlab doesn't show anything because those data are beyond amx and min axis values. I want data that are on the current window, not from stored plot function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose `xp` and `yp` are the x and y coordinates of all of the points.  You can remove the points outside of `[-320 320 -240 240]` like this:

```
ii = xp < -320 | xp > 320 | yp < -240 | yp > 240;
xp(ii) = [];
yp(ii) = [];
```

Comment: @Makaroni, note that if you don't know the limits, they are in the XLim and YLim properties of your axes.

Comment: Thanks nibot. Although its not direct solution, it gives what I want.